# Much different result when using numba

Tags: python, numba

I have here pure python code, except just making a NumPy array. My problem here is that the result I get is completely wrong when I use @jit, but when I remove it its good. Could anyone give me any tips on why this is?

```
@jit
def grayFun(image: np.array) -> np.array:
      
    gray_image = np.empty_like(image)
    
    
    for i in range(image.shape[0]):
        for j in range(image.shape[1]):
            gray = gray_image[i][j][0]*0.21 + gray_image[i][j][1]*0.72 + gray_image[i][j][2]*0.07
            gray_image[i][j] = (gray,gray,gray)
    
    gray_image = gray_image.astype("uint8")
    return gray_image
```

Comment: It's not good practice to use a variable with the same name as your function.  You do not need to do that as a loop; you can do that as a single line in numpy.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, I just changed the name for the post, forgot that I had gray in the code. will try to see how to do it as a single line. Than you

Comment: The problem with your code is that you make an array with `np.empty_like` and then you _use those values to compute the gray value_. But the contents of an array made with `np.empty_like` is garbage (it's arbitrary data and can be very large numbers).

Comment: yeah - can you check the code in the question you posted @ili? it doesn't work at all as it's currently written. I think you want to define `gray` using `image` not `gray_image`. I'm interested in taking a swing at the `@jit` issue (which is not addressed by Tim Roberts's answer) but your code doesn't work in python *or* numba right now.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado hello sir, not quite sure how I get the right result then. I can try to explain my thinking. The reason i use gray is to score some value i just put inside the gray_image, if i put it directly in gray_image i would get an error

Comment: I'm saying you need to replace `gray = gray_image[i][j][0]*0.21 + ...` with `gray = image[i][j][0]*0.21 + ...`. as the code is currently written you're computing the value `gray` from the result of `np.empty_like`, not from `image`. This is what @jkr is pointing out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will return a grayscale image with your conversion formula.  USUALLY, you do not need to duplicate the columns; a grayscale image with shape (X,Y) can be used just like an image with shape (X,Y,3).

```
def gray(image):
   return image[:,:,0]*0.21+image[:,:,1]*0.72 + image[:,:,2]*0.07
```

Comment: sorry if this question is stupid but, with this one line of code, how will all the values in the grayscales array be changed? because it looks like it just returns the sum. The code you sent worked but I just do not understand it

Comment: This is why I did this                                                                                                        gray = gray_image[i][j][0]*0.21 + gray_image[i][j][1]*0.72 + gray_image[i][j][2]*0.07
gray_image[i][j] = (gray,gray,gray) Because i thought we need to change values by indexing

Comment: the description here is key - Tim is taking a shortcut by returning a 2D array rather than a 3D array because most image rendering tools will accept a 2D array and render it as grayscale, so there's no need to return a 3D array. Usually. But this doesn't address the thrust of your question, which I think either has to do with using an unallocated array to define gray, or is a typing or tuple issue.

Comment: Because `numpy` works with the array as a whole.  That's what makes it such a huge win..  `image[:.:.0]` returns a 2D array sliced from your 3D array.  The `*0.21` operation then multiplies every element by that value, and the `+` operations do matrix addition to return a 2D array that is your grayscale value.

Comment: Using matrix multiplication may be faster: `image @ [0.21, 0.72, 0.07]`

Answer (score 2):

This should work just fine with numba. [@TimRobert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73841309/3888719) is definitely fast, so you may just want to go with that implementation. But the biggest win is simply from vectorization. I'm sure others could find additional performance tweaks but at this point I think we've whittled down most of the runtime & issues:

```py
# your implementation, but fixed so that `gray` is calculated from `image`
def grayFun(image: np.array) -> np.array:
    gray_image = np.empty_like(image)
    for i in range(image.shape[0]):
        for j in range(image.shape[1]):
            gray = image[i][j][0]*0.21 + image[i][j][1]*0.72 + image[i][j][2]*0.07
            gray_image[i][j] = (gray,gray,gray)
    gray_image = gray_image.astype("uint8")
    return gray_image

# a vectorized numpy version of your implementation
def grayQuick(image: np.array) -> np.array:
    return np.tile(
        np.expand_dims(
            (image[:, :, 0]*0.21 + image[:, :, 1]*0.72 + image[:, :, 2]*0.07), -1
        ),
        (1,1, 3)
    ).astype(np.uint8)

# a parallelized implementation in numba
@numba.jit
def gray_numba(image: np.array) -> np.array:
    out = np.empty_like(image)
    for i in numba.prange(image.shape[0]):
        for j in numba.prange(image.shape[1]):
            gray = np.uint8(image[i, j, 0]*0.21 + image[i, j, 1]*0.72 + image[i, j, 2]*0.07)
            out[i, j, :] = gray
    return out

# a 2D solution leveraging @TimRoberts's speedup
def gray_2D(image):
   return image[:,:,0]*0.21+image[:,:,1]*0.72 + image[:,:,2]*0.07
```

I loaded a reasonably large image:

```py
In [69]: img = matplotlib.image.imread(os.path.expanduser(
    ...:     "~/Desktop/Screen Shot.png"
    ...: ))
    ...: image = (img[:, :, :3] * 256).astype('uint8')
    ...: 

In [70]: image.shape
Out[70]: (1964, 3024, 3)
```

Now, running these three reveals a slight speedup from numba, while the fastest is the 2D solution:

```py
In [71]: %%timeit
    ...: grey = grayFun(image)  # watch out - this takes ~21 minutes
    ...:
    ...:
2min 56s ± 1min 58s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [72]: %%timeit
    ...: grey_np = grayQuick(image)
    ...:
    ...:
556 ms ± 25.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [73]: %%timeit
    ...: grey = gray_numba(image)
    ...:
    ...:
246 ms ± 19.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [74]: %%timeit
    ...: grey = gray_2D(image)
    ...:
    ...:
117 ms ± 10.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Note that numba will be noticeably slower on the first iteration, so the vectorized numpy solutions will significantly outperform numba if you're only doing this once. But if you're going to call the function repeatedly within the same python session numba is a good option. You could of course use numba for the 2D result to get a further speedup - I'm not sure if this would outperform numpy though.

Comment: thank you sir, I have a question, the method Tim proposed. Is that not vectorized?

Comment: Tim's is definitely vectorized. I was calling the 3D method the vectorized version of your answer because it returns the same data but operates on the whole array at once. Tim's does the same thing, but is even faster because it doesn't return a 3D (tiled) copy of the array - just the 2D version.